# MC60E GSM Shield can't connect to Network

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm

I am using a GSM MC60E Shield (Model: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=234200.0) on top of an Arduino Mega 2560; the Arduino is connected to other sensors that are not important now.
I want to take values stored in the Arduino Mega and send them via the GSM MC60E Shield to my phone every 12h.
But I am stuck at a previous step: the GSM MC60E can't connect to the network. I turn it on by holding the power button for 4s, the redLED is supposed to flash every 2s when it is on. I am not sure if...

- It is a problem of the code. I read rx and tx should be connected opposite. But since it is a shield, how can I oppose them?
- It is a physical connection problem (weird because there are no cables or anything, only the shield on top of the Arduino and the USB Port to the computer)

So far this is the code that has worked. It stops at the output "Waiting for Network..." and then "fail":

```
/**********************
 *
 * This sketch connects to a website and downloads a page.
 * It can be used to perform HTTP/RESTful API calls.
 *
 * TinyGSM Getting Started guide:
 *   https://tiny.cc/tinygsm-readme
 *
 **********************/

// Select your modem:
//#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM808
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM868
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM900
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7000
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM5360
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7600
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_UBLOX
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SARAR4
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_M95
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_BG96
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_A6
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_A7
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_M590
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_MC60
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_MC60E
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_ESP8266
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_XBEE
// #define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SEQUANS_MONARCH

// Set serial for debug console (to the Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial

// Set serial for AT commands (to the module)
// Use Hardware Serial on Mega, Leonardo, Micro
#define SerialAT Serial1

// or Software Serial on Uno, Nano
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//SoftwareSerial SerialAT(1, 0); // RX, TX

// Increase RX buffer to capture the entire response
// Chips without internal buffering (A6/A7, ESP8266, M590)
// need enough space in the buffer for the entire response
// else data will be lost (and the http library will fail).
#if !defined(TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER)
#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER 650
#endif

// See all AT commands, if wanted
// #define DUMP_AT_COMMANDS

// Define the serial console for debug prints, if needed
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon

// Range to attempt to autobaud
#define GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN 9600
#define GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX 115200

// Add a reception delay - may be needed for a fast processor at a slow baud rate
// #define TINY_GSM_YIELD() { delay(2); }

// Uncomment this if you want to use SSL
// #define USE_SSL

// Define how you're planning to connect to the internet
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS true
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI false

// set GSM PIN, if any
#define GSM_PIN ""

// Your GPRS credentials, if any
const char apn[]  = "YourAPN";
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";

// Your WiFi connection credentials, if applicable
const char wifiSSID[]  = "YourSSID";
const char wifiPass[] = "YourWiFiPass";

// Server details
const char server[] = "vsh.pp.ua";
const char resource[] = "/TinyGSM/logo.txt";

#include <TinyGsmClient.h>

// Just in case someone defined the wrong thing..
#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS && not defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_HAS_GPRS
#undef TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
#undef TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS false
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI true
#endif
#if TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI && not defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_HAS_WIFI
#undef TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
#undef TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS true
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI false
#endif

#ifdef DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
  #include <StreamDebugger.h>
  StreamDebugger debugger(SerialAT, SerialMon);
  TinyGsm modem(debugger);
#else
  TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
#endif

#ifdef USE_SSL
  TinyGsmClientSecure client(modem);
  const int  port = 443;
#else
  TinyGsmClient client(modem);
  const int  port = 80;
#endif

void setup() {
  // Set console baud rate
  SerialMon.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // !!!!!!!!!!!
  // Set your reset, enable, power pins here
  // !!!!!!!!!!!

  SerialMon.println("Wait...");

  // Set GSM module baud rate
  TinyGsmAutoBaud(SerialAT, GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN, GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX);
  // SerialAT.begin(9600);
  delay(6000);

  // Restart takes quite some time
  // To skip it, call init() instead of restart()
  SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.restart();
  // modem.init();

  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  SerialMon.print("Modem Info: ");
  SerialMon.println(modemInfo);

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
  // Unlock your SIM card with a PIN if needed
  if ( GSM_PIN && modem.getSimStatus() != 3 ) {
    modem.simUnlock(GSM_PIN);
  }
#endif
}

void loop() {

#if TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI
  // Wifi connection parameters must be set before waiting for the network
  SerialMon.print(F("Setting SSID/password..."));
  if (!modem.networkConnect(wifiSSID, wifiPass)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");
#endif

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS && defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_XBEE
  // The XBee must run the gprsConnect function BEFORE waiting for network!
  modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass);
#endif

  SerialMon.print("Waiting for network...");
  if (!modem.waitForNetwork()) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (modem.isNetworkConnected()) {
    SerialMon.println("Network connected");
  }

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
  // GPRS connection parameters are usually set after network registration
    SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
    SerialMon.print(apn);
    if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
      SerialMon.println(" fail");
      delay(10000);
      return;
    }
    SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (modem.isGprsConnected()) {
    SerialMon.println("GPRS connected");
  }
#endif

  SerialMon.print("Connecting to ");
  SerialMon.println(server);
  if (!client.connect(server, port)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  // Make a HTTP GET request:
  SerialMon.println("Performing HTTP GET request...");
  client.print(String("GET ") + resource + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  client.print(String("Host: ") + server + "\r\n");
  client.print("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  client.println();

  uint32_t timeout = millis();
  while (client.connected() && millis() - timeout < 10000L) {
    // Print available data
    while (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      SerialMon.print(c);
      timeout = millis();
    }
  }
  SerialMon.println();

  // Shutdown

  client.stop();
  SerialMon.println(F("Server disconnected"));

#if TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI
    modem.networkDisconnect();
    SerialMon.println(F("WiFi disconnected"));
#endif
#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
    modem.gprsDisconnect();
    SerialMon.println(F("GPRS disconnected"));
#endif

  // Do nothing forevermore
  while (true) {
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your code has a lot of `serialmon.print` statements ... why are you not including the serial monitor output in your post?

Comment: @jsotola Since the GSM is not connected, the code stucks at "Waiting for Network..." "fail".